# Determine the values of a, b and c, for which the systems have (1) exactly one solution, (2) no solutions, (3) infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

I will just attach a picture. Can someone help me to solve this? I think I missed some information. [image]

Comment: Your work looks correct to me. Note that $a-2b+c=0$ is the equation of a plane

Comment: Thanks, @pwerth , but I need to determine the values for a,b and c. I have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: My point is that there is no way to simplify the answer any further than saying "all values of a,b,c such that $a-2b+c=0$", which you could rephrase as "all points on the plane $a-2b+c=0$. There are obviously infinitely many such points so there is no way you can write them all down

Comment: I'll also point out that since you exhausted both cases, you proved that there are no values of $a,b,c$ for which the system has a unique solution.

Comment: @pwerth I had this task when my group in college did not start planes. So, there must be a way how to make an answer except yours. I lost my notes, that's why it's hard for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same result as you: If $$a-2b+c=0$$ then we get infinity many solutions. If $$a-2b+c\ne 0$$ then we get no solutions.Since the last two equations are $$x_2+2x_3=\frac{4a-b}{3}$$ and $$x_2+2x_3=\frac{7a-c}{6}$$